# Xamarin Forms on iOS left margin issue on ListViews

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an existing Xamarin Forms iOS app, that I want to rebuild in order to fix some issues. I update my Visual Studio for Mac and updates my NuGet packages. The Xamarin.Forms package is upgraded to version 2.4.0.74863. I compile the app, and everything works, except that ListViews gets an extra margin on the left side. The yellow area indicates this.

[image]

The same Android Xamarin Forms app does not have this extra margin.

Is this a known Xamarin Forms/iOS issue? And is there a workaround to solve this issue?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jgold6/70fabb558aee86e03db6

Comment: It looks like the default display of the table view in iOS, see here:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1

Comment: @KevinLi Appears to be correct.  And if you look at various Apple iOS apps that use a ListView, you see the same uneven margin.  It's even in many screenshots in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.  [https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Xamarin.Forms for iOS introduced in Xamarin.Forms version 2.4.0.74863

It is an issue only on iOS 11.

See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60636

Comment: I will try to go back to Xamarin.Forms version 2.4.0.18342